# WildFly localhost 'forbidden' access

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly

I am trying to create a Jakarta, JAX-RS and wildfly enviroment. I can startup a deployment and access the wildfly homepage. But when i want to access my resources (e.g. @Path("/health")). I receive a FORBIDDEN error:

[image]

When I looked at the management console I saw that there is no `JAX_RS` deployedL

[image]

I am utterly lost at what to do. Can somebody help

I have tried adding management and application users, creating a web.xml, creating a extension of Application, creating a CORS filter, updating my pom.xml file

Comment: We need to know more about your application. Is it a WAR? Do you have a `web.xml` file? Do you have a type that extends `jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application` with a `@ApplicationPath` annotation? What version of WildFly are you using?